# Historical lock for "barriers to understanding pointers"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, historical-lock

I just came across this old deleted question (10k only): [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

It was first asked back in August 2008, was closed as "too broad" by two normal users and a mod in February this year, and was deleted by the combined votes of 10 ordinary users in mid-November.  At the time of deletion, the question had a score of 443, and the top answer was at 585, with almost 40k views.

To me, this question seems like a poster child for [historical locking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) — it was once considered on topic for Stack Overflow, and was one of the top questions on the site, with several excellent answers, but changing community norms have since left questions like it outside the scope of SO as currently understood.

I would thus like to request that this question be undeleted and locked by a moderator.  Objections?

Comment: Can't read the question and don't know the history of the deletion/closing decisions, I know a lot of users object to locking because the question is effectively frozen in time, especially the fact that they can't be edited, so when answers become out dated, the existing answers can't be fixed or improved upon.

Comment: 40K views over 5 years is nothing.  That's well below the threshold for a historical lock.

Comment: If we really trusted the community then we should accept that such a highly upvoted question *is* on-topic for the site. The up-votes indicate that the community find it useful. If norms really have changed then in time it will be down-voted into oblivion, and if it is *then* (and only then) should it be deleted. But that's just my opinion :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question does not deserve a historical lock. A historical lock is reserved for:

- Blatantly off topic questions that meet the following criteria:

  - Lots of views (over 100K; but generally 350K+)
  - Lots of votes (multiple hundreds)
  - Lots of people linking to it
  - The fact that the information inside of it won't be obsolete -- it'll still be useful in a few years.

However, this answer should not be deleted. Understanding pointers are a common enough problem (I still have issues with them in practice, which is probably why I'll never get that job at Fog Creek or Stack Overflow) that there will be people asking that question. We need somewhere to point them to for a duplicate.

More importantly, it also has really, really, really good information in it.

We should not delete useful information. That doesn't coincide with our mission to make the internet a better place.

What we can do is institute a wiki lock. It's sort of the best of both worlds:

- Those that closed the question don't have to worry about any more answers
- Those that want the question to not be deleted get their wish
- And information in the answers can still be edited/improved

[Previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251665/when-should-old-list-of-x-questions-be-kept-as-wikis), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262518/should-how-do-javascript-closures-work-be-locked-as-a-community-wiki-no-furt), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266158/when-can-a-question-become-locked-against-new-answers-when-theres-a-community-w), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266859/can-my-old-question-get-a-collaborative-effort-lock), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222285/could-you-moderators-stop-deleting-community-wiki-questions), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112935/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112940/16587).

Comment: What a wiki lock _doesn't_ do, however, is telling people "this question _is not considered a good on-topic question for SO_, but it's somewhat valuable so we keep it around". IMO the lock text should be included to add that notice; or at least the question should always be closed regardless of the lock to send a clear signal (which is the case here, but see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1012573/1110381)).

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that doesn't seem to be consistent for all questions with wiki locks - the question I linked was explicitly reopened by a mod even though it is clearly not on-topic. Are there any "official" guidelines on this?

Comment: @l4mpi [Yup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266158/when-can-a-question-become-locked-against-new-answers-when-theres-a-community-w).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Might it make sense to remove the "Too broad" close reason as the "Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." message is a little confusing in this instance?