# Historical lock for "how to explain to people how difficult your project is"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

Can we get a historical lock for this post (or delete it)?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268718/how-to-explain-to-people-how-difficult-your-project-is

It's very old, and off-topic as per today's standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason for a historical lock on this question.  George Stocker lists a series of guidelines for applying a historical lock in [Historical lock for "barriers to understanding pointers"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280530/historical-lock-for-barriers-to-understanding-pointers/280534#280534)

> Blatantly off topic questions that meet the following criteria:
>
> - Lots of views (over 100K; but generally 350K+)
> - Lots of votes (multiple hundreds)
> - Lots of people linking to it
> - The fact that the information inside of it won't be obsolete -- it'll still be useful in a few years.

This meets none of these categories (ok, I can't tell if "Lots of people linking to it" is met, but I can guess that it doesn't since it only has ~730 views as of this writing).

The question is off-topic, just vote to close it (as enough people have done now).  It will eventually be downvoted enough to make it eligible to deletion.